# I cannot connect to the internet via ethernet (Bell Canada Fibe Modem)

Tags: web-server

I am a totally new Raspberry Pi user.  After connecting all the cables into their proper places, the Pi (model B) is on but I cannot connect to the internet.

My internet service provider is Bell Canada.  It is "Fibe" (DSL?) and the router is a Sagecom F@st2864.

I connect my Pi to the router using an ethernet cable.

Is there anything else that I need to do so that I can use my Pi to surf the net, check my Gmails and watch YouTube?

Comment: if you post `ifconfig` output that would be great and very helpful for people to answer your questions.

Comment: Welcome- Please upvote answers and then mark the correct one or the one that helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Guidelines to troubleshoot internet connectivity to Pi:

1. First, verify that the router is able to connect to the internet[Test with another PC/laptop].
2. If all goes well, connect a cross-cable from the router to Pi, open a terminal[eg: LXTerminal] in Pi and execute:

   ```
          i) $ping 127.0.0.1 [to check if the tcp/ip stack is functioning properly.]
         ii) $ifconfig
   ```
3. Look out for the network configuration of eth0 from the output.
4. If entry for eth0 is not shown, possibly the port is disabled, and needs to enabled.

   ```
      $sudo iface eth0 up   [activating the eth0 port]
      $/etc/init.d/networking restart [restarting the networking deamon ]
      $ifconfig     [again to see ifconfig appear this time]
   ```
5. Since most routers run DHCP service,you will be assigned a dynamic ip address by router
   when you connect pi.

   ```
     $leafpad /etc/network/interfaces [edit this file to check the n/w settings].
   ```

   Check out that the following line is enabled, and all other configurations for the eth0 port is commented out.

   **iface eth0 inet dhcp**
6. I hope you have discovered where you went wrong by now.

P.S: If still in trouble or you are unable to understand how a  specific configuration, you may leave a comment, so that i can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Which port did you plug the cable into? The 2864 has five ports on the back: a red WAN-ETH port, and four yellow LAN[1234] ports. You want to use one of the yellow ones. Pictures of the ports here: [User Manual: Sagemcom 2864 / TekSavvy Solutions Inc](https://support.teksavvy.com/posts/608610-user-manual-sagemcom-2864/public)

There are, unfortunately, many ways to configure one of these beasties. If it's set up in the standard Bell way, the wired ports *should* work automatically. I run mine in bridge mode through a router for TekSavvy, and everything behaves quite differently.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. It turns out the ethernet cable bell gave me worked with my laptop but not with the raspberry pi. take a careful look at each end and confirm that they have all the wires in the connectors.